# HTML rowspan row uneven heights on mobile

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am working on a table which makes use of `rowspan` since the rowspan is applied to the first column in  the row, other columns have multiple rows.. I have made the application responsive so that it is applicable for mobile devices as well..

When I resize, row height is evenly distributed as given in the picture below

[image]

But on iPhone and iPad it looks like this. I tested it in Chrome and Safari on iPad and iPhone both. Results the same.. I tried it on Android device and it works well.

[image]

Well, since I expect HTML should resize it evenly.. I don't have control over styling as well. Any idea why this is happening?

**Sample Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/cseuj5tu/1/**

Please help if you know.

Comment: How about posting some code or making Fiddle??

Comment: Hi @Richa, I have added sample in main question. http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/cseuj5tu/1/embedded/result/ Check this on iPhone or iPad you'll see the row height is uneven on iOS devices only.

Comment: @Richa let me know when you see this comment. Or you can contact me on twitter hande @_rahulpp need help :-)